# The application has failed to start cause its side-by-side configuration is incorrect

Tags: c#, dll, native, dllimport

I am doing a project which is creating a native DLL. If I run the DLL file it works well in my machine. If I use the same DLL in some other machines it gives  a error file. The error is:

> The application has failed to start because its side-by-side
>   configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or
>   use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail

So I need to open the application event and check the error log. The Error log says:

> Dependent Assembly
>   Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="9.0.21022.8"
>   could not be found. Please use sxstrace.exe for detailed diagnosis.

Comment: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-pictures/error-the-application-has-failed-to-start-because/df019c0d-746e-42d0-ad68-465e18e3f3ef

Comment: codroipo I already read the article and install those files. but no use

Comment: I had same error and it was due to few invalid xml characters in my config file.

Answer (score 0):

> Dependent Assembly Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="9.0.21022.8" could not be found. Please use sxstrace.exe for detailed diagnosis.

The information you need can be found here. Your DLL links against the debug C++ runtime. The debug runtime cannot be re-distributed. In order to install the debug runtime you must install the compiler. But that's the wrong solution to your problem. The right solution is to link against the release runtime. Compile your DLL as a release build, and distribute that. You will, of course, need to ensure that the Visual Studio 2008 C++ runtime is installed on the target machine.

Comment: thanks dude.. I will change it to release build and the target machine contain VS2008 C++ redistributable. Still Now I got the same error.. What should I do??